# Is it problematic to pray for a sick person at night?

Tags: tefilla

Some Siddurim only have the special tefillah for a choleh that is sometimes added into the bracha of Re'fa'einu in the Shachris tefillah and not by Ma'ariv. Is that because davening for a choleh at night is less beneficial than davening by day, due to the fact/concept that night is a time of din/judgement and mazikin and not a time of rachamim?

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a Siddur? I don't know that I've ever seen one. What does it have for Mincha?

Comment: in shmona esre of Arvit we say refaenu venerappe

Comment: Besides the answer, below, I'm curious as to why you would think there is a problem. If your parent had emergency surgery at night, wouldn't you pray for him / her?

Answer (score 3):

Both [this](http://halachayomit.co.il/he/ReadHalacha.aspx?halachaid=391) site and [this](http://www.hidabroot.org/question/98198) site discuss praying for a sick person at night and allow it (along with sources) - including saying Tehilim, even according to those who don't say Tehilim during the first half of the night (for kabbalistic reasons).

They do not mention that praying at night for sick people is any different to praying for them during the day.

Comment: Welcome back Danny !!!!!!!!!!!!!